# Selective Encoding with HttpUtility.Encode for Special Characters (i.e. μ)

Tags: c#, html, character-encoding, special-characters

I have read that it's a good idea to encode strings in HTML (via HttpUtility.Encode) to prevent script exploits. Having said that, I have a string that includes special characters such as μ, and since I want the string to display correctly regardless of encoding, I have opted to use the HTML string literal to do that, which is &#xb5 for μ, instead of setting the HTML encoding to UTF-8 explicitly. However, if I encode this string, the & gets encoded to &amp, and the μ character doesn't display properly. Therefore, I was wondering if there's a way to not encode &#xb5 even if I choose to encode the rest of the string.

I have created a small example below to illustrate the issue:

```
string text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("random string with text and 100 &#xb5s");
string[] lines = { "<html>", "<body>", text, "</body>", "</html>" };
string curFile = @"C:\Test.html";
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(curFile, lines);
```

This gives "random string with text and 100 &#xb5s" instead of the desired "random string with text and 100 µs" in the HTML output.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: Any particular reason why you can't use HtmlAgilityPack to create HTML?

Comment: The typical reason - this is inherited legacy code :)